# Define drawable and layout for Galaxy Nexus

Tags: android, layout, drawable

I'm developing an app that must work for multiple device screens, so, I separated the drawable and layout folders properly: large-land, large-port, sw720dp and so on.

For devices like Nexus, from Google, I'm having a problem with its menu, that is in OS, not physical, like in others devices. 
So, layouts that works well in devices like SIII does not work on Nexus, it seems like shrunken, because I lost a litte of its height.

Discussing with friends, we thought in set its layout programatically, but in a screen with various elements, it's bad to keep. Is there a way to organize this layout and drawable using the android's structure, like I did for others resolutions and sizes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide screenshots of your problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

for the nexus 7 from Asus it will use the drawables in folder drawable-xhdpi so put the drawables there ... and for icons use 48x48 size so they will look the same size as an actionbar icon ...

Comment: Hi Driss, sorry for delay, and thanks for your anwser. It was very helpful for us.